# How can I docker commit azure container instance to azure container registry

Tags: docker, azure-acr

We have ansible configured to deploy our various applications on IIS environment. I am trying to create a docker image of deployed applications so that I can just start up containers as we need for testing and otherwise.

I am planning to build on the [Windows IIS](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore-iis) image, start the container on azure, run our ansible to install everything on the server, then save the image on container.

I cannot find any documentation on how I can `docker commit` the container image into our private azure container registry.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an existing Docker registry in azure you should be able to use the `az acr login --name myregistry` command to authenticate to it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli. Make sure you have a registry created for the container image you want to push up.

Next, you can run the container in azure and do all the installation you want. SSH or RDP into the instance in Azure that is running this container. Now run `docker ps` and find the container id for the correct container. Next, use `docker commit <container id> myregistry.azurecr.io/samples/nginx`.

Then, just `docker push myregistry.azurecr.io/samples/nginx`

Also not sure what your use case is, but starting a container in order to modify and commit it in that way seems like an atypical use case for Docker since the build isn't reproducible via the Dockerfile. Looks like there are ways to replace Dockerfiles using Ansible playbooks with something like ansible-containers https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/ so you might want to take a look at that(I've never used this tool).

Comment: But isn't running `docker ps` going to return the list of containers running on my local machine rather than the containers running on Azure?

Comment: Yes you will need a way to ssh or rdp into the azure instance that is running your containers. Edited my answer to clarify that.

Comment: I wanted to run azure container instance, which is the container itself. How can it log into the container host in this case?

Comment: If you meant running the container within a VM which will be a container host, I am currently exploring that option. But the problem now is that I don't know how to publish the container so that it is available to my Ansible server to performs installations. I have created a new questions here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55661511/how-to-configure-windows-server-2016-with-dns-sub-domains-to-an-ip-address-in-th

Comment: Yeah if you want to commit the container in a certain state you will need to be able to access the host that's running that container. I'm not as familiar with azure or ansible but you'll need a host address and then the mapped host port to access the container. So let's say we have a host with an address of 192.168.1.233 and we start a container on that host with `docker run -d -p 9000:80 nginx`. Then we can hit the nginx container at 192.168.1.233:9000.

Comment: Also not sure what your use case is, but starting a container in order to modify and commit it in that way seems like an atypical use case for Docker since the build isn't reproducible via the Dockerfile. Looks like there are ways to replace Dockerfiles using Ansible playbooks with something like ansible-containers https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/ so you might want to take a look at that(I've never used this tool).

Comment: Ansible container is really my answer here for my use case, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your code is in the Github repo(the procedure is the same if you're using other repos like Bitbucket and etc.)

In the root of your repo, you can create **.github** folder, and create another folder in the name of **workflows** You can place your yml files inside this folder so the github know where to look for changes:
I'm creating simple example here:

```
# This is your mydeployment.yml file: 

name: Publish IIS

# Configures this workflow to run every time a change is changed on a path.
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'path/to/mypackages'
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - 'path/to/mypackages'
# on:
#   push:
#     branches: ['main'] #you define your branch here
# There is a single job in this workflow. It's configured to run on the latest available version of Ubuntu.
jobs:
  deploy-IIS-to-ACR:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    # Sets the permissions granted to the `GITHUB_TOKEN` for the actions in this job.
      # 
    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v1
    # Uses the `docker/login-action` action to log in to the Container #registry registry using the account and password that will publish the #packages. Once published, the packages are scoped to the account defined here.
    - name: Log in to the Container registry
      uses: Azure/docker-login@v1
      with:
        login-server: myregistry.azurecr.io
        username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}
    - name: build the image
      run: |
        docker build --file "Path/to/your/docke" -t myregistry.azurecr.io/samples/nginx .
        docker push myregistry.azurecr.io/samples/nginx
```

The credentials for logging into the ACR can be placed inside the github secrets as environmental variables.
As you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/), you have quite a lot's of flexibility in configuration of building your image. Check this